# What does the word "palpable" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

From [an answer on another Stack Exchange website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565551/c-sharp-winforms-threading-closed-form-gets-invoked) (StackOverflow):

> Given how rare this will be, that ugly hack could be palpable.

It sounds like the author is saying that the solution might be viable? suitable? sufficient? I can deduce what he means from the context.

I am confused because having searched for the definition of the word "palpable" I cannot find an applicable definition. I like the word and  if the usage is correct I might like to use it myself.

Did the author use the word "palpable" correctly? If so [which definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/palpable) is applicable?

Comment: Either _It could become so intensely bad coding it could be touched and felt_ or the other _Easily perceived; obvious_

Comment: Having read it in context, I would say no, the author did not use palpable correctly. As a metaphor it means "so obvious it's like you can physically feel it with your hands" and is used to refer to tension, fear, stress, "the stakes", excitement, disappointment etc. This answer seems to use it to mean "ok" or "something you can use" or "acceptable."

Comment: I do not know "computerspeak" but did the person who used the word "palpable" mean to use the word "culpable," meaning, roughly, "guilty of" or "blameworthy"?  In other words, the hack is to blame, or is guilty of doing something bad.  Just a thought.

Comment: @rhetrorician I tried to avoid making the question esoteric. I think the word "hack" is being used to describe something that isn't ideal but does the job.

Comment: @KateGregory My thought exactly. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: The answer was edited a half hour ago. He changed it to "that ugly hack could be acceptable."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because even the person who wrote the "unusual" usage admits he made a mistake.


Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just murdered that one, can only claim not being a native English speaker as an excuse.

I meant *palatable*.

Sorry.

Comment: Lol[.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565551/c-sharp-winforms-threading-closed-form-gets-invoked#comment25309843_3565820)

Comment: didn't notice it was you, Hans. And I honestly never knew English was not your first language.

Comment: Born and raised in the Netherlands, Dutch is my native language.  My first job there after university got me into the USA.

Comment: @HansPassant You're an interesting guy. You're also quite the enigma :-p